# Number of primefactors in $ f(n,W) = \prod_{k=1}^W (p_k^n -1) \text{ where } p_k=Prime(k) $

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm reviving an old fiddling, although I do not yet really see its benefit. Beginning with the eulerproduct for the zeta-function in the representation $\small \zeta(n)=\prod {1\over 1-p^{-n} } = \prod {p^n \over p^n-1 }$ I asked whether it might be meaningful to try to find an asymptotic expression for the occurences of primefactors in the denominator, depending on the number *W* of Eulerterms and then exponent *n*. So I define 
$$\ z(n,W) = \prod_{k=1}^W p_k^n - 1 \qquad p_k \in \mathbb P $$ 
and count the primefactors $\small q_k $ (with multiplicity) in 
$$\small z(n,W) = q_1^{a_{1,n}} q_2^{a_2} q_3^{a_3} \ldots  $$
Of course this is increasing with *W* and erratically. But due to the randomness and seemingly uniform distribution of the primes with respect to their moduli to any primes I seem to get meaningful constants for the first few, say 20, primes $\small q_k$ when W goes to 10000 or to 100000 and I evalute their relative frequencies $\small z(n,W)/W $.
I get the provisorical formula for the exponents of the primefactors $\small q_k \gt 2$ 
$$ {a_{k,n}\over W} \sim gcd(n,q_k-1)\cdot {q_k + (q_k - 1)\{n,q_k\} \over (q_k -1)^2} $$ where the bracketed expression means "exponent of primefactor $\small q_k$ in *n* "

My first question is: can this be justified? If I understand things correctly, this would require, that the primes are not only equally distributed modulo any prime, but even modulo any prime-power, and in general completely "symmetric" , just like $\small \mathbb N $ it self.

My second question concerns the primefactor $\small q_1 = 2$ Here I concluded from the achieved numerical evidence, that the same formula is asymptotically valid with a small correction
$$ {a_{k,n}\over W} \sim gcd(n,q_k-1)\cdot {q_k + [2|n]+ (q_k - 1)\{n,q_k\} \over (q_k -1)^2} =  2 + [2|n] + \{n,2 \} $$
where the iverson-bracket $\small [2|n] $ evaluates to *1* or *0* depending on whether *2* divides *n* or not.   From the construction of the whole expression it looks reasonable under the hypothese, that the distribution of primes *(mod 2)*, *(mod 4)*, *(mod 8)* etc is also "symmetric" in the long run. But after a closer look it seems, that there is a nonneglectable small error of *2%* say: for *W=10000* I expect for exponent *n=1* $\small a_1=20000$ but empirically *46* are missing; for *W=20000* I get *96* missing and for *W=30000* I get *127* missing. (Some more example in that region for *W* suggest, that this is not a fluctuation around a zero-error, but has a bias)

Question 2: Is there some systematic reason for that bigger error with the primefactor 2? And if, what would be a better aymptotic formula/formula for the relative frequency of that primefactor?

---

table for relative frequencies of primefactors q_k( horizontal) and n (vertical), scaled by $\small (q_k-1)^2$, rounded to integers, based on the first *W=60000* terms of the Eulerproduct:
$$ \small
\begin{array} {r|rrrrrr}
 n  & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 11 & 13 & 17 & 19 & \text{ primefactors } q_k \\
\hline \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 11 & 13 & 17 & 19 \\
 2 & 4 & 6 & 10 & 14 & 22 & 26 & 34 & 38 \\
 3 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 21 & 11 & 39 & 17 & 57 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 & 20 & 14 & 22 & 52 & 68 & 38 \\
 5 & 2 & 3 & 9 & 7 & 55 & 13 & 17 & 19 \\
 6 & 4 & 10 & 10 & 42 & 22 & 78 & 34 & 114 \\
 7 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 13 & 11 & 13 & 17 & 19 \\
 8 & 6 & 6 & 20 & 14 & 22 & 52 & 136 & 38 \\
 9 & 2 & 7 & 5 & 21 & 11 & 39 & 17 & 171 \\
 10 & 4 & 6 & 18 & 14 & 110 & 26 & 34 & 38 \\
 11 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 21 & 13 & 17 & 19 \\
 12 & 5 & 10 & 20 & 42 & 22 & 156 & 68 & 114
 \end{array} $$
For instance the primefactor $\small q_3=5 $ occurs asymptotically in *10* of $\small (5-1)^2 =16 $ cases, or, if W=16000 for the denominator of the partial Eulerproduct with exponent *2*, then we'll have about $\small 10 \cdot W/16 = 1000 $ occurences of the primefactor 5.

*I've put this question also with a bit more better(?) explanation in [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83904) and have received one answer (which does however not cover the whole question)*